# Converting and printing hex values using sprintf(keeping the leading zeroes)

Tags: c++, c, io, hex, printf

I have the following C code which takes two long integer values and convert them to two hex strings using the sprintf function:

```
void reverse_and_encode(FILE *fpt, long *src, long *dst) {
    char reversed_src[5], reversed_dst[5];
    sprintf(reversed_src, "%x", *dst);
    sprintf(reversed_dst, "%x", *src);
    printf("Reversed Source: %s\n", reversed_src);
    printf("Reversed Destination: %s\n", reversed_dst);
}
```

But when I print the hex value strings, I can't get the leading zero in the output. Eg.

```
Reversed Source: f168 // for integer 61800
Reversed Destination: 1bb // This output should be "01bb" for integer 443
```

Comment: `"%x"` -> `"%08x"`. Read the documentation of `printf`.

Comment: Oh and 5 in `reversed_src[5]`  and ` reversed_dst[5]` is a bit small for a `long`.

Comment: "keeping leading zeros" does not make sense. There is nothing to "keep". If you want to *pad* it with certain number of zeros, you should state with how many.

Comment: If you are programming in C ("...the following C code"), then why the C++ tag?  C and C++ are distinct languages.  C++ has `std::string` for text, C doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sprintf(reversed_src, "%04x", ( unsigned int )*dst);
```

Pay attention to that in general if the the expression `2 * sizeof( long )` (the number of hex digits) can be equal to 8 or 16.for an object of the type long. So you need to declare the arrays like

```
char reversed_src[2 * sizeof( long ) + 1], reversed_dst[2 * sizeof( long ) + 2];
```

and then write for example

```
sprintf(reversed_src, "%0*lx", 
        ( int )( 2 * sizeof( long ) ), ( unsigned long )*dst);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N  = 2 * sizeof( long ) };
    char reversed_src [N + 1];

    long x = 0xABCDEF;

    sprintf( reversed_src, "%0*lX", N, ( unsigned long )x );

    puts( reversed_src );
   
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0000000000ABCDEF
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. Helpful for storing the values as is also.